# Alternative to dynamic creation of variable names

Tags: c++

I have a header file (not written by me, which I cannot change) which contains definitions in the following format:

```
#define     SPC_TMASK0_NONE         0x00000000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH0          0x00000001
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH1          0x00000002
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH2          0x00000004
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH3          0x00000008
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH4          0x00000010
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH5          0x00000020
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH6          0x00000040
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH7          0x00000080
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH8          0x00000100
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH9          0x00000200
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH10         0x00000400
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH11         0x00000800
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH12         0x00001000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH13         0x00002000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH14         0x00004000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH15         0x00008000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH16         0x00010000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH17         0x00020000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH18         0x00040000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH19         0x00080000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH20         0x00100000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH21         0x00200000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH22         0x00400000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH23         0x00800000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH24         0x01000000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH25         0x02000000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH26         0x04000000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH27         0x08000000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH28         0x10000000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH29         0x20000000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH30         0x40000000
#define     SPC_TMASK0_CH31         0x80000000
```

I have a function which is accepts a channel number (0-31) and I want to find the corresponding macro expansion (SPC_TMASK0_NONE, SPC_TMASK0_CH0... etc).

I thought that creating the macro expansion dynamically (as a string) would be the easiest/neatest/cleanest but it seems that I can't do that so can someone suggest a better alternative to go from channel number to macro expansion?

I know that the number corresponding to the macro expansion could be used directly, but this has the potential to change so I need to use the names to ensure correct operation over time.

I really don't want a big if else / switch case - I was thinking of an array with the names in and the channel number is used to select the element but that felt clunky as well.

Comment: Just to be clear, the channel number is a runtime parameter and is unknown at compile-time, right?

Comment: You probably want `1u << channel`.

Comment: @Quentin, that's right.

Comment: @ Jarod, as stated, that would work, but if the author of the .h changed all the numbers everything would break - I can't accept that.

Comment: Else the array seems fines to me.

Comment: If array is the best way to do it, no problem, it just seemed a clunky way of doing it., I wondered if there were better ideas.

Comment: If the author changed the numbers then you have a different number. I'm not clear on what you're trying to obtain - a string name? Or?

Comment: As currently written these macros are worthless, you can just write a function to make bit mask from bit index.

Comment: The macros explain what the value is doing so someone can read the code and understand what the values used does. If it was just numbers then people would have a hard time understanding what was going on.

Comment: If the author changed the number then they would also change what it did (I have to assume) - so, for example, they flip the sequence and 0x00000001 now enables the trigger for channel 31 - if I just generate the channel number from the channel given to the function then I get the wrong channel enabled. If I always use "SPC_TMASK0_CH31" then I know I get channel 31 enabled regardless of what happens in the device driver. (Or should do, but if that doesn't works it's not my fault..)

Comment: In that case, you can have a *function* `int SPC_TMASK0(int)`. If the definition changes, you change the *body* of that function, and all the usages are unaffected

Comment: @Caleth, I have about 50 of these to write, I really don't want to have to change them all if there is a big update, I really need an approach which uses the macro names so, as long as the names continue to mean the same thing in the context of the device driver, I'm always safe.

Comment: Better to have the constexpr array initially instead of (evil) MACRO.

Comment: Agreed, but the header is supplied by an external company and whilst I could ask them to rewrite it I'm not sure they'd listen.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to map a runtime integer to a macro's value, your best bet is indeed an array. But you don't have to write it yourself!

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>

constexpr auto channelMask(int channelNumber) {
    constexpr std::uint32_t array[] {
#define detail_channelMask_case(z, n, data) \
    BOOST_PP_CAT(SPC_TMASK0_CH, n),

    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(32, detail_channelMask_case, ~)

#undef detail_channelMask_case
    };

    return array[channelNumber];
}
```

This generates the array with the macros 0 to 31, and indexes into it. I leave it to you to handle input limits and the `SPC_TMASK0_NONE` macro :)

Comment: This looks like what I need (especially because there are about 50 of these arrays of macros) I really needed a way of doing it without having tons of extra code.  Thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear, does this define the macros, or create a reference to them? The macros are already defined, I would just like to reference them by channel number. So; array = [SPC_TMASK0_NONE, SPC_TMASK0_CH0 ....] --> myVal = array[channelNumber]

Comment: @TimMottram It uses the macros.

Comment: @TimMottram it only references them to fill up the array, yes.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, sorry I am a beginner really and haven't used much boost. I saw the #define and thought you wanted me to rewrite the header.

Comment: 10/10 would use Boost.PP again